# Should I create 3 different widgets for each page/screen of my app to be able to run on different size screens?

Tags: flutter, responsive, screen-size

I am trying to work on a project that should be run on web, tablet and mobile platforms. I think there are 2 approaches to do this:

1- Create 3 different widgets for each page of the app. For example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResponsiveLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget mobileBody;
  final Widget tabletBody;
  final Widget desktopBody;

  ResponsiveLayout({
    required this.mobileBody,
    required this.tabletBody,
    required this.desktopBody,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        if (constraints.maxWidth < 500) {
          return mobileBody;
        } else if (constraints.maxWidth < 1100) {
          return tabletBody;
        } else {
          return desktopBody;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

2- Create only one widget for each screen but check the screen size like `mediaquery.of(context).size.width`  whenever I want to show something differently on web than mobile or table.

I don't know there is also a third approach or which approach is better for big application/projects?

Comment: I don't think it's a definitive answer, but I'm making apps for phones and tablets. If you use `MediaQuery.of(context).size` to adjust the ratio, the layout may be slightly different depending on the size of each device, so I wrote the sources for Phone and Tablet separately.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/sizer

It is very helpful when working for multiple screen sizes.
From their README:

- h - Returns a calculated height based on the device
- .w - Returns a calculated width based on the device
- .sp - Returns a calculated sp based on the device
- SizerUtil.orientation - for screen orientation portrait or landscape
- SizerUtil.deviceType - for device type mobile or tablet

Answer (score 1):

Basically, these are 2 ways to handle it.

The tradeoffs here are complexity, flexibility, speed of development and consistency:

- if you create 3 separate widgets, you might need to spend more time to preserve consistency (copy code changes between widgets) sometimes, but each widget would be more or less simple to understand.
- if you use MediaQuery.of(context) and all the changes automatically propagate to all the versions (which might be a good or a bad thing) and it's way more flexible (i.e. you can show/hide/change some parts of the widget at width < 500 and others at width < 1200), but the code might slowly turn into an unreadable mess.

Here's more info in the official [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/building-adaptive-apps)